# strange errors compiling c code

Tags: c, gcc

I have the code below I am trying to build

```
#include stdio.h
#include stdlib.h
#include signal.h
#include wiringPi.h
#include softPwm.h

void control_event(int sig);
int HARD_PWM_PIN=1; Hardware PWM Pin(GPIO18-12)
int SOFT_PWM_PIN=0; Software PWM Pin(GPIO0-11)
int DELAY_MS=10;
int main(void)
{
  (void)signal(SIGINT,control_event);
  (void)signal (SIGQUIT,control_event);
  printf(Hardware and software based PWM test on LEDn);
  if(getuid()!=0) wiringPi requires root privileges
  {
    printf(ErrorwiringPi must be run as root.n);
    return 1;
  }
  if(wiringPiSetup()==-1)
  {
    printf(ErrorwiringPi setup failed.n);
    return 1;
  }
  pinMode(HARD_PWM_PIN,PWM_OUTPUT); setup hardware pwm
  softPwmCreate(SOFT_PWM_PIN,0,100); setup software pwm pin
  int up;
  int down;
  while(1)
  {
    for(up=1;up=5;down--)
    {
      pwmWrite(HARD_PWM_PIN,down);
      softPwmWrite(SOFT_PWM_PIN,down);
      delay(DELAY_MS2);
    }
    delay(DELAY_MS5);
  }
}
void control_event(int sig)
{
  printf(bbExiting...n);
  pwmWrite(HARD_PWM_PIN,0);
  softPwmWrite(SOFT_PWM_PIN,0);
  delay(100); wait a little for the pwm to finish write
  exit(0);
}
```

But I keep getting the following errors this is only a portion of them but they are pretty much the same throughout with the odd symbols and numbers.

```
test1.c:20:1: error: stray â\302â in program
test1.c:20:1: error: stray â\240â in program
test1.c:21:1: error: stray â\302â in program
test1.c:21:1: error: stray â\240â in program
test1.c:22:1: error: stray â\302â in program
test1.c:22:1: error: stray â\240â in program
test1.c:23:1: error: stray â\302â in program
test1.c:23:1: error: stray â\240â in program
test1.c:23:1: error: stray â\302â in program
test1.c:23:1: error: stray â\240â in program
test1.c:24:1: error: stray â\302â in program
test1.c:24:1: error: stray â\240â in program
test1.c:24:1: error: stray â\302â in program
test1.c:24:1: error: stray â\240â in program
test1.c:25:1: error: stray â\302â in program
test1.c:25:1: error: stray â\240â in program
test1.c:26:1: error: stray â\302â in program
test1.c:26:1: error: stray â\240â in program
test1.c:26:38: error: unknown type name âsetupâ
test1.c:26:53: error: expected â=â, â,â, â;â, âasmâ or â__attribute__â before âpwmâ
```

What could be wrong? The place I am getting this code from is [here](http://www.rpiblog.com/2012/11/pwm-on-raspberry-pi.html)

Comment: `int HARD_PWM_PIN=1; Hardware PWM Pin(GPIO18-12)` that's hardly correct C syntax... is `hardware pwm pin...` suppsoed to be a comment? missing a `//` in that case.

Comment: You probably used a word processor and got 'smart quotes' in place of ASCII double quotes.  This is not good.  You're `#include` lines do not match either of the standard forms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have some syntax errors -

- aside from that your editor  included unicode characters instead of the ASCII expected by gcc. - a possible example for " as a backward double quote or forward double quote instead of ASCII 34.

You have to be careful about your editor settings when you are using a non-western character set or extended unicode as your default encoding.

This is also why  " characters do not show up in your post.

Answer (score 3):

The odd symbols and numbers are because some of the spaces in the file aren't actually spaces.  Looking at some of the lines in the file in your link, after copying and pasting:

```
'void control_event(int sig);\n'
'int HARD_PWM_PIN=1; //Hardware PWM Pin(GPIO18-12)\n'
'int SOFT_PWM_PIN=0; //Software PWM Pin(GPIO0-11)\n'
'int DELAY_MS=10;\n'
'int main(void)\n'
'{\n'
'\xc2\xa0 (void)signal(SIGINT,control_event);\n'
'\xc2\xa0 (void)signal (SIGQUIT,control_event);\n'
'\xc2\xa0 printf("Hardware and software based PWM test on LED\\n");\n'
'\xc2\xa0 if(getuid()!=0) //wiringPi requires root privileges\n'
```

Those `\xc2\xa0`s are the non-breaking space characters (`&nbsp;`), or `302/240` in octal.

Also note that you seem to have lost several comment markers (`//`) in transit, which is causing different problems of its own as the compiler is trying to interpret comments as code.